# iOS - FBLoginView Issue when account is integrated on device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the following code to create a FBLoginView in my application:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = 
  [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_birthday", 
  @"user_likes", @"user_location", @"user_photos", @"read_stream", 
  @"status_update", @"user_about_me", @"read_friendlists", 
  @"friends_about_me", @"friends_birthday", 
  @"friends_photos"]];
```

This works fine, when the device has no Facebook account setup within the Settings App, however when an account is setup within the Settings App, the FBLoginView simply does nothing.

I am assuming this is default behaviour, and is for some reason required, but does anyone know what the work around should be if Facebook integration is enabled on the device?